# How can display scaled dimension of an image using lightbox?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox

I use the lightbox control (http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ ) to display an image.
but the control always display a full dimension image, how can I do if I hope to display an half dimension of an image? Thanks!

```
/* line 7, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
body:after {
  content: url(../img/close.png) url(../img/loading.gif) url(../img/prev.png) url(../img/next.png);
  display: none;
}

/* line 11, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

/* line 20, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* line 28, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* line 32, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}

/* line 35, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* line 38, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/utilities/general/_clearfix.scss */
.lb-outerContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* line 44, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-container {
  padding: 4px;
}

/* line 47, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

/* line 56, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-cancel {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat;
}

/* line 63, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* line 71, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-container > .nav {
  left: 0;
}

/* line 74, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
}

/* line 77, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-prev, .lb-next {
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Trick IE into showing hover */
  display: block;
}

/* line 84, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-prev {
  left: 0;
  float: left;
}
/* line 87, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-prev:hover {
  background: url(../img/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
}

/* line 90, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-next {
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}
/* line 93, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-next:hover {
  background: url(../img/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
}

/* line 96, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-dataContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
/* line 38, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/utilities/general/_clearfix.scss */
.lb-dataContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* line 103, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-data {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
}
/* line 106, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-data .lb-details {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
/* line 111, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-data .lb-caption {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
}
/* line 115, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-data .lb-number {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999999;
}
/* line 121, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-data .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../img/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/* line 130, ../sass/lightbox.sass */
.lb-data .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: That's really vague.  Are you trying to set the width through javascript?  You could just add a targetable class to the image and use CSS to define the height/width as a percentage

Comment: It seems it is good way to use CSS to define the height/width as a percentage , but I don't know how to modity source code.

Comment: You shouldn't need to.  Just add the classes to your image list items.  It'd be helpful if you could setup a jsbin or post some sample code.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted CSS in my question, but I don't know how to modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted has been compiled from sass.
To change the width of the lightbox image you'll have to find the declaration that governs the width of the modal container, which looks like it might be:

```
.lightbox .lb-image {
    width: 50%;  /* reduce the image width to half of its original x dimension */
    height: auto; /* keep height set to auto, otherwise you might distort the image */
}
```

Without seeing the HTML it's a little difficult to say whether the `.lb-image` class is targeting the `img` or its container.  In the case of the latter, the `height: auto` declaration shouldn't be necessary.

This change should be made to the source (non-compiled) sass file `../sass/lightbox.sass`
You'll then have to recompile the sass to get the output that's then applied to the page.

For more info about sass and scss check out their website http://sass-lang.com/